# Difficulty with demonstratives

Tags: gender, pronoun

How do you know what demonstrative to use when you are not aware of the gender of the noun you are referring to?

For example I keep seeing questions like this in my exercises:

> Er ist der Besitzer dies...

Do I use *dieses*, *dieser* or *dies*?

Comment: Each post should only contain one question (unless of course they are intrinsically linked in a way that makes splitting them unfeasable). I therefore removed your second question, but do feel free to ask it in a separate post!

Comment: Was soll hinter 'dies' beispielsweise folgen können? 'Dieses Messers, dieser Gabel, dieses Löffels', ja, aber 'dies ...?'

Comment: _Er ist der Besitzer davon._

Comment: In case you’re starting a sentence and are unsure of what the actual word is, I would go ‘Er ist der Besitzer dieses… dieser … dieses … dieser Flasche!’ while lengthening the shwa of *dieses/dieser* to show my uncertainty ;)

Answer (score 5):

There simply is no way. You need to know the gender of the word to make a correct sentence:

> Er ist der Besitzer dieses Hofes. (*der Hof*)
>   Er ist der Besitzer dieser Wohnung. (*die Wohnung*)
>   Er ist der Besitzer dieses Hauses. (*das Haus*)
>   Er ist der Besitzer dieser Grundstücke. (*die Grundstücke*, plural of *das Grundstück*, but the gender does not matter in plural)

Note that it is not possible to omit the noun in this genitive construction, or at least it would be highly unusual to say *Er ist der Besitzer dieses*.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is:

### You will not know it.

The gender of the demonstrative pronoun depends on the noun to which it refers. If the noun (or just it's gender) is unknown, the gender of the pronoun (and so the pronoun itself) is unknown.

**btw:**
In this case *dies* is always wrong, because in Genitiv case you only can have *dieser* or *dieses*:

> singular:
>   male: Er ist der Besitzer **dieses** Baums.
>   female: Er ist der Besitzer **dieser** Blume.
>   neuter: Er ist der Besitzer **dieses** Messers.
>
> plural (all genders): Er ist der Besitzer **dieser** Bäume/Blumen/Messer.