# Verwendung von Personalpronomen mit Objekten in der dritten Person Singular

Tags: gender, personal-pronoun

Kann man immer "er" oder "sie" verwenden, wenn man über Gegenstände spricht? Wie zum Beispiel:

> 1. Der Bus kommt. Aber **er** ist zu spät.
> 2. Die Flasche steht auf dem Tisch. **Sie** ist voll.
> 3. Das Leben ist seltsam. Versucht nicht, **es** zu verstehen.

Darf man auch "es" für alle Fälle verwenden, oder nur dann, wenn der Artikel nicht bekannt oder Neutrum ist?

Für mich fühlt es sich manchmal so seltsam an, dass ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob ich es richtig gelernt habe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Frage ist nicht, ob man kann oder nicht. Man muss. Alles andere wäre falsch.

- Richtig:

  > Der Bus kommt. Aber **er** ist zu spät.
  > Die Flasche steht auf dem Tisch. **Sie** ist voll.
- Falsch:

  > <del>Der Bus kommt. Aber **es** ist zu spät.</del>
  > <del>Die Flasche steht auf dem Tisch. **Es** ist voll.</del>

Anders als z.B. im Englischen, wo Substantive kein grammatisches Geschlecht haben, hat im Deutschen jedes Substantiv eines von drei grammatikalischen Geschlechtern (in Ausnahmefällen sind auch mehrere Geschlechter möglich).

Da englische Substantive kein grammatikalisches Geschlecht haben, können in dieser Sprache die (mit einem Geschlecht behafteten) Pronomen gar nicht mit dem grammatikalisches Geschlecht des Substantivs übereinstimmen, weil es letzteres gar nicht gibt. Stattdessen stimmen englische Pronomen mit dem biologischen Geschlecht jener Sache überein, die vom Wort benannt wird, wobei es z.B. bei Schiffen auch Ausnahmen gibt.

Das grammatikalische Geschlecht deutscher Pronomen stimmt aber immer mit den grammatikalischen Geschlecht jenes Substantivs überein, auf welches das Pronomen verweist.

Zu beachten ist auch, dass das grammatikalische Geschlecht eine Eigenschaft des Wortes ist, nicht des Gegenstandes, der durch das Wort benannt wird!

Beispiele für ein und dieselbe Sache (ein großes altes Auto), die verschiedene Namen mit verschiedenen Geschlechtern hat:

- männlich

  > Der Wagen ist rostig. **Er** steht in der Garage.
- weiblich

  > Die Karre ist rostig. **Sie** steht in der Garage.
- sächlich

  > Das Auto ist rostig. **Es** steht in der Garage.

Wie man gut sehen kann, ist das Geschlecht eine Eigenschaft des Wortes, nicht der Sache. Es ist dieselbe rostige alte Limousine, über die wir hier sprechen, aber da wir verschiedene Substantive mit unterschiedlichen Geschlechtern verwenden, müssen wir auch das Pronomen ändern.

(*Der Wagen* wird oft für ein größeres Auto, wie eine Limousine, verwendet. *Die Karre* wird oft für ein altes und schäbiges Auto verwendet. *Das Auto* ist das allgemeine Wort.)

---

Da im Deutschen jedes Substantiv ein grammatisches Geschlecht hat, kommt der Fall, dass das Geschlecht unbekannt ist, gar nicht vor. Das Personalpronomen *es* wird daher nur verwendet, wenn es sich auf sächliche Substantive bezieht.

Comment: Der Fall kommt schon vor, wenn man nicht weiß, was man bezeichnet. Umgekehrt dann aber doch nicht, weil man dann *das Ding* oder *es* gedanklich einsetzt. (Beispiel: »Was ist denn das?«)

Comment: @Jan: Das haben wir schon vor 5 Jahren abgehandelt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25262/difficulty-with-demonstratives

Answer (score 4):

> Kann man immer "er" oder "sie" verwenden, wenn man über Gegenstände spricht?

Man verwendet immer das Pronomen, das dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht entspricht. Genau so, wie es in den Beispielen angegeben ist.

> Darf man auch "es" für alle Fälle verwenden

Nein.

> oder nur dann, wenn der Artikel nicht bekannt oder Neutrum ist?

Ich weiß nicht, in welchen Fällen der Artikel nicht bekannt sein sollte. Falls Fälle gemeint sind wie beispielsweise, dass man nicht weiß, ob es *der Junge* oder *das Mädchen* ist, benutzt man den abstrakteren Begriff *das Kind* und dementsprechend das Pronomen *es*.

Comment: My understanding is that for *Mädchen* in particular, it becomes more and more likely that the *es* will turn into a *sie* the farther you get from where the person was introduced, especially in spoken language. But I think that's the only exception. Grammatical gender does seem strange if your native language (like English) doesn't use it, But German is actually rather typical of European languages here.

Answer (score 1):

Das das Substantiv ersetzende Pronomen wird immer im selben Geschlecht wie das Substantiv selbst verwandt.
Möchte  ich also im ersten Beispiel den Bus (maskulin/männlich) ersetzen muss immer das maskuline/männliche Pronomen ("Aber **er** ist zu spät) verwendet werden.
Gleiches gilt für weibliche Substantive, die durch sie "ersetzt" werden und sächliche/neutrale die durch es "ersetzt" werden.